# Sending My Own Arguments To A Event Handler?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm working with AssemblyResolve specifically.  Here is my code first, then my question follows:

```
var a = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
a.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleIt);

Private Assembly HandleIt(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args){
    //Does stuff, returns an assembly
}
```

So I add HandleIt to my AssemblyResolve event.  How can I add it to that event and pass an argument with it like:

```
a.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleIt(AnArgument));
```

This is throwing me off since HandleIt takes arguments, but none are explicetly passed when it is added to the AssemblyResolve event.  I would expect something like:

```
a.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleIt(aSender,someArgs));
```

So yeah, I just want to be able to send another argument to my HandleIt function when adding it to my AssemblyResolve event.

Hope that makes sense, thanks.

Addendum:

```
if(aBool){
    a.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleA);
}
else{
    a.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleB);
}

HandleA(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args){
    Handle(true);
}
HandleB(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args){
    Handle(false);
}
Handle(bool isA){

}
```

-vs-

```
if(aBool){
    a.AssemblyResolve += (object s, ResolveEventArgs a) => Handle(s,a,true);
}
else{
    a.AssemblyResolve += (object s, ResolveEventArgs a) => Handle(s,a,false);
}

Handle(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args, bool isA){

}
```

Comment: You don't need the if(aBool) in the lambda version, you can simply say`a.AssemblyResolve += (object s, ResolveEventArgs a) => Handle(s,a,aBool);`or what ever the argument should be

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the event is fired arguments are passed to the method if you would like to bind additional arguments you could do that with a lambdaexpression

```
var a = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
a.AssemblyResolve += (object s,ResolveEventArgs a) => HandleIt(s,a,someArgument);

Private Assembly HandleIt(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args, SomeType arg){
    //Does stuff, returns an assembly
}
```

where someArgument is the value you wish to bind.

This is essentially using lambdas to do a partial application of a function. Something that C# doesn't support directly but is very common in other languages. Partial application is very closely related to Currying that exists in languages such as F# and Haskell of course (since the concept gets it's name from Haskell Curry) and various other functional langauages. They differ in the result type.

They are both related to closures (as the concept in the above code is called) and in languages that don't support partial application or currying you can use closures to accomplish something similar. However be aware that closures differ from partial application in ways that can create some surprising bugs. E.g.

```
int i = 1;
Func<int> f = () => i;
i = 2;

System.Console.WriteLine(f());
```

prints `2` to the console. Because closures captures a **reference** to a variable not the value of said variable. This is a common error in for loops, when closing over the loop variable(s) of the for loop.

Comment: Voted for this instead of my answer

Comment: This doesn't help in achieving his goal in manually triggering the event. See the update in my answer.

Comment: @Daniel where in the question does it say anything about manually triggering the event?

Comment: Can you see my addendum?  Lambda expressions just seem kind of messy (this is only what my blind intuition tells me), but they do simplify the code.  Which is the best approach?

Comment: He says so in his comment to asawyer's answer.

Comment: @sooprise I guess it depends on your background and how many different methods you'd need to accomplish what you're looking for (speaking in general terms not for this question)

Comment: Fair enough.  The more I look at it though, the more lambda expressions make sense.  I've had a hard time in my programming to embrace lambda expressions, just because they are very unintuitive to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain will raise the event and pass parameters, the += line is simply registering a handler to the event, parameters there would not make any sense.

Analogy:

You register your address with the postman, and he deilivers mail to that address later. When you register at the post office, you do not hand them the mail you want delivered to you later!

Comment: Sure, I can see my understanding is even worse that I thought it was before.  Maybe it doesn't even make sense what I'm trying to do, which is this: I'm intentionally triggering AssemblyResolve to choose my own DLL to load at runtime.  I want to be able to say: load this or that dll by passing an argument to my AssemblyResolve event handler.  Does that change anything?

Comment: Look at Rune FS's answer. Also, if this is what your trying to do, this should have been your question!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. 
HandleIt in this case is a delegate to and has to match the signature of ResolveEventHandler

```
a.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleIt);
```

Setting it in this line just tells the code what to execute when AssemblyResolve is raised the thing that raises the AssemblyResolved event will pass it's parameters. You could re-raise another event with your own parameters and hook that to another handler (or just call a method).

EDIT: Or maybe you can with Lamda's :o

Comment: Would this be the "best practice" approach?  I can see I can add arguments kind of messily via lambda expressions.

Comment: This is what I have done in the past for this kind of problem. That lambda thing is pretty slick though.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more technical: You are registering a delegate to your method with the event. This is something else than a call to the method.
It is a bit similar to this:

```
Action<object, ResolveEventArgs> handleItDelegate = HandleIt;
```

When the event is fired, the delegate is invoked. The analogy of my sample would be:

```
handleItDelegate(sender, eventArgs);
```

UPDATE:
In a comment, you clarified, what you want to achieve: You want to trigger the event, so your assembly is loaded. You can't do that, the way you think it works. To load your assembly manually, just do so, no need for the event. The event is called, when the runtime tries to resolve a referenced assembly, but can't find it.